# Truncation error in Store procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert details into Emp Table which is successfully been done.
But my requirement is to truncate table first the next time when i again try to insert the details.
Hence i had written truncate statement which keeps on truncating the lines one by by one.

Result is the last line of the file which appears into the table.

Can someone help me to modify the procedure?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Deatils]

    @Name(100),
    @DESCRIPTION(100),
    @Address(100)


    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @CountNew varchar(100)   

    set @CountNew=(select count(*) from [dbo].[Emp_Details] ) 
    if @CountNew>=1 

    truncate table [dbo].[Emp_Details] 
    else

          INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp_Details]
           ([Name],
        [DESCRIPTION],
        [Address]
    )
         VALUES
               (

    @Name,
    @DESCRIPTION,
    @Address
    )
    END

    Begin
    if exists(select 1 from [dbo].[Emp_Details] where Name='Raul')

    Delete from [dbo].[Emp_Details] where AIRCRAFT_REGISTRATION='Raul'

    End
```

Comment: Question is not clear at all. *Result is the last line of the file which appears into the table.* Can you elaborate on this

Comment: Are you saying this table should only ever have one row in it? Where does the 'file' come into it? Please post the code that calls this stored procedure?

Comment: ... or are you saying that if you call this SP with parameters that represent and already existing record, the record should not insert, just update?

Comment: basically,i have to perform bulk insert in one shot.

Comment: why `declare @CountNew varchar(100)` ? why not `declare @CountNew int` ?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to take into consideration...

`TRUNCATE` deletes all rows in a table, and resets any `IDENTITY` columns. It's an operation that is not logged in the transaction logs, and thus very fast.

`DELETE` will remove the rows, but the action will be logged. Also, any IDENTITY columns will not be reseeded.

If you simply want to empty the table when you start running the proc, you could suffice with this:

```
TRUNCAE TABLE [dbo].[Emp_Details] 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp_Details]
([Name], [DESCRIPTION], [Address])
VALUES
(@Name, @DESCRIPTION, @Address)
```

The `DELETE` at the end should only be used if you need to get rid of specific results before handing back the results of the `INSERT` operation. If your goal is to empty the table when you fire the proc again, the truncate will take care of that.

There's also something about the last few lines that looks off to me.

```
Begin
if exists(select 1 from [dbo].[Emp_Details] where Name='Raul')

Delete from [dbo].[Emp_Details] where AIRCRAFT_REGISTRATION='Raul'

End
```

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
if exists(select 1 from [dbo].[Emp_Details] where Name='Raul')
Begin
   Delete from [dbo].[Emp_Details] where AIRCRAFT_REGISTRATION='Raul'
End
```

(Again, not necessary if your only goal is to empty the table)

Also, you hint at there being an error, but did not post the error.

Comment: @Schmitz-Thanks for reply..but my task is to truncate the table at start and insert all values in one shot.

Comment: @Raul - Ok. But the proc is still going to update one row at a time. Wouldn't it be easier to do a truncate, and then a bulk insert instead? That way you'd not need a proc to do a row-by-row insert.

Comment: That entirely depends on how you get the data that you use to then call the stored procedure as it exists now.  am guessing you have some kind of a `SELECT` statement that fills a `CURSOR` or temp table, from which you then process row-by-row using the proc. If you want us to help you, try and post the code you use prior to executing the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections in the `Stored Procedure` please see if this suffices your requirement.

Ok got your requirement now,
Call the `TRUNCATE` statement prior to the `Loop` or `Bulk Insert`. This ensures that the `Table` is empty to insert the new records.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp_Details]
```

Then call the `Procedure` which would do the insert for you into the `Table`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Deatils]
@Name VARCHAR(100),
@DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
@Address VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp_Details]
        ([Name],[DESCRIPTION],[Address])
         VALUES
        (@Name,@DESCRIPTION,@Address)


    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Emp_Details] WHERE NAME = 'Raul')

        DELETE FROM [dbo].[Emp_Details] WHERE AIRCRAFT_REGISTRATION = 'Raul'
    END 
END
```

Or You can use the `Table-Valued Parameters` to do pass all the rows in a single shot.

```
CREATE TYPE Emp_Details AS TABLE   
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Deatils]  
    @Tmp Emp_Details READONLY  
    AS
    BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp_Details] 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp_Details]   
           ([Name]  
           ,[Description]  
           ,[Address])  
        SELECT   [Name]  
                ,[Description]  
                ,[Address]  
        FROM  @Tmp;

        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Emp_Details] WHERE NAME = 'Raul')

            DELETE FROM [dbo].[Emp_Details] WHERE AIRCRAFT_REGISTRATION = 'Raul'
        END 

    END  
GO 

/* Declare a variable that references the type. */  
DECLARE @Emp AS Emp_Details;  

/* Add data to the table variable. */  
INSERT INTO @Emp ([Name], [Description], [Address])  
    SELECT [Name], [Description], [Address]
    FROM Emp_Details1;  

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */  
EXEC [dbo].[Insert_Deatils]  @Emp;  
GO
```

You can check the [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) for more info on the same

Tried the below sample at my end and it seems to Work fine

```
USE <Database>
GO

CREATE TYPE Emp_Details AS TABLE   
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO


CREATE TABLE Emp_Details
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO 


CREATE TABLE Emp_Details1
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO 


INSERT INTO Emp_Details1 VALUES ('John','Test','123')
INSERT INTO Emp_Details1 VALUES ('John1','Test1','1234')
INSERT INTO Emp_Details1 VALUES ('John2','Test2','1235')
GO

SELECT * FROM Emp_Details

/* Declare a variable that references the type. */  
DECLARE @Emp AS Emp_Details;  

/* Add data to the table variable. */  
INSERT INTO @Emp ([Name], [Description], [Address])  
    SELECT [Name], [Description], [Address]
    FROM Emp_Details1;  

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */  
EXEC [dbo].[Insert_Deatils]  @Emp;  
GO 

SELECT * FROM Emp_Details
```

Comment: @joby-Even this wont work as the stored procedure would be called for first time and data would be inserted and again on calling the SP ..it would again truncate the data and second row would be inserted.This would keep on repeating till last row..I need to truncate data once and insert the data in one shot.

Comment: @Raul yup I understood your requirement, so have updated it :)